# Tool for generates c# class initializators

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, code-generation

I have a boring task to write unit tests. So i need to create fake data.

Can i automate this process? 
For example take data from database and generate c# code based on class instances. 
Or maybe just take data from files in json\any other format.

Answer (score 1):

I personally don't know any tool to generate data from database on .net. Something that could help you on the process of creating data for tests is a factory helper like [Plant](https://github.com/jbrechtel/plant) or [FactoryGirl.NET](https://github.com/JamesKovacs/FactoryGirl.NET)

I'm currently using `Plant` in a project and worked really well for me.

**Plant Usage**

To create a new Plant, you'll typically want to tell it which Assembly to look in for Blueprints. You can do this via

```
var plant = new BasePlant().WithBlueprintsFromAssemblyOf<PersonBlueprint>();
```

where PersonBlueprint is one of the Blueprints you have defined. Plant will then load blueprints from any other type that implements the Blueprint interface in that assembly.

To retrieve the default instance of an object

```
var person = plant.Create<Person>();
```

To retrieve an instance of a person with specific parts of the default blueprint overridden

```
var person = plant.Create<Person>(new 
{ 
    EmailAddress = "john@doe.com" 
});
```

Multiple properties can be overridden in one call

```
var person = plant.Create<Person>(new 
{ 
    EmailAddress = "john@doe.com", 
    State = "GA" 
});
```

To define a Blueprint property that is evaluated lazily, but with a sequence counter, set the value to new Sequence(lambda) like so:

```
class PersonBlueprint : Blueprint
{
    public void SetupPlant(BasePlant plant)
    {
        plant.DefinePropertiesOf<Person>(new
        {
          ID = new Sequence<int>((sequenceValue) => sequenceValue)
          Name = new Sequence<string>((sequenceValue) => "test: " + sequenceValue)
        });
    }
}
```

**FactoryGirl.NET Usage**

To define a factory:

```
FactoryGirl.Define(() => new User 
{
    FirstName = "John",
    LastName = "Doe",
    Admin = false
});
```

To use a factory:

```
var user = FactoryGirl.Build<User>();
```

To customize the object being built:

```
var admin = FactoryGirl.Build<User>(x => x.Admin = true);
```

Comment: I seen Plant and FactoryGirl.NET but i cann't understand what benefits  i can get using these libraries. Enumerable.Range(1,10).Select(x => new Person(){...}) give me instances with any fields which i want. Why i should use plant.Create<Person>(... if i can just write new Person(){...}?

Comment: @Neir0: 1) You centralize the instaces creation in one place so you avoid repetitive code and make tests simpler 2) instance creation can be done trough a "template" so is simplified. Using sequences on `Plant` helper provides interesting possibilities to generate different instances with the same template.